# Failed to resolve Firebase auth 15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase

I am new to android development environment and I need to connect my app to firebase but I am getting this error

> Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0

This error is shown in the statement:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

This statement contain details of two versions, I think the error is caused due to this, but this particular statement is provided by firebase itself. See the image:

[image]

I tried to change the above statement to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

But then firebase dependency is not setting up.

Comment: try clean your project and then rebuild it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

Replace the above one with

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

Insert these two lines:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
```

Warnings should disappear

Comment: I had the same issue mentioned above by @Raju but with version 19 (`implementation com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0`). After that changed as your answer, `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'` it was solved. By doing that can it cause any further issues?

Comment: I believe not, try it.The latest versions are 19.1.0 and 17.2.1, respectively

Answer (score 2):

Try to use only `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'` in your code.

In your root build.gradle file add the repo:

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried this too, but then the firebase dependency is not setting up.

Comment: Have you paster google-services.json in your app folder of Android project?

Comment: Yes I have pasted JSON file

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: When I add implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1' code compiles successfully but the firebase assistant still does not connect with dependency. When I click on add dependency it again asks me add the statement implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'

Comment: But can you use the functionality of the repo? it doesn't matter what the assistant wants ;)

Comment: No, I not able to use the functionality, my mail authentication is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Check if your firebase core is the same version than your firebase auth

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

and in your classpath an up version of 3.0.0

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' //up of this version
```

check this page to be up to date with firebase version:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions

Answer (score 1):

Try This add the dependency for Authentication to your app-level build.gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

Comment: When I add implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1' code compiles successfully but the firebase assistant still does not connect with dependency. When I click on add dependency it again asks me add the statement implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'

Answer (score 1):

Worked with me, follow me.
I had this same problem. In the implementation of dependencies they are with the implementation 'com.google.firebase: firebase-auth: 16.0.2' ". The first is usually implemented manually and the second when we click the add button authentication with Firebase by the console in Android Studio and that is where the error begins. This button does not need to be triggered to authenticate the app. Just the first button to Connect with Firebase.
In the build.gradle file, keep only one Auth dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Add firebase-core dependency and the latest versions of dependencies from this page:
[fire base libraries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?authuser=0)

Answer (score 1):

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'`

Replace the above with this -->

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'`

Comment: If you're hoping it would work, then it would be better if you add it as a comment. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I updated the Android Studio and the Gradle ,it seems to work fine now

Comment: How to update the Android and the Gradle? I installed Android studio Yesterday but it was giving the same error when I try to set path! However, i solved it by adding ```implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0' implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'``` instead. But if can tell how to update those woud be appreciated!