# Faild to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase

I am new to android development environment and I need to connect my app to firebase but I am getting this error

> Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0

This error is shown in the statement:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0' //16.0.1
```

I tried to change the above statement to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
```

But then firebase dependency is not setting up.

Comment: Extra versions added: :`16.0.1:15.0.0` Just use : `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'` And make sure you have `google()
    jcenter()` in the root build.gradle. You'll need to update the gradle too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve Firebase auth 15.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557175/failed-to-resolve-firebase-auth-15-0-0)

Comment: Solved this yet?

Answer (score 2):

You should use **`firebase-auth:16.0.4`** version.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
```

**FYI**

At first, add rules to your **root-level** `build.gradle` file, to include the google-services plugin and the Google's Maven repository:

```
buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0' // google-services plugin
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...
    repositories {
        // ...
        google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
```

After that, **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Read [**`Add Firebase to Your Android Project`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Answer (score 1):

Update the dependency to the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
```

Also add `firebase-core`:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Please also update google-services plugin in top level gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```