# Dependancy error when integrating android studio project with Firebase for a google sign in feature

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an app in Kotlin and keep getting the error:

> Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0`

when trying to sync gradle. I'm trying to implement a google sign in feature.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "nus.is3261.kotlinapp"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'

}
```

I have tried to follow the solution on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52557175/failed-to-resolve-firebase-auth-15-0-0), but I am left with this warning after syncing gradle  `Warning: The app gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0

Because you are using a wrong dependency in your code. To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
```

Because such a version `16.0.1:15.0.0` does not exist.

Please also add the following dependency which is now mandatory:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

> Your app gradle file now has to explicitly list `com.google.firebase:firebase-core` as a dependency for Firebase services to work as expected.

In your top level `build.gradle` file please be sure to have the latest version of Google Service plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'`

By `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'`

Also add Firebase Core dependency
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'`

Move your `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to bottom of build file

Comment: I am left with this warning: `Warning: The app gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.` after changing. I'm wondering if it will be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

add

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I make this the "add firebase authentication..." dissapear. You know... in android studio, the firebase assistant menu gives a quickly way to set firebase services. When click on "Add Firebase Authentication to your app" button, android says:

```
app/build.gradle

build.gradle will include these new dependencies:


compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
ACCEPT CHANGES? -> YESSSS
```

and then the sync fail. If I replace this with:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
```

firebase will not add to my app.